# Difference between beat and beat out

Tags: grammar, phrasal-verbs

I'm wondering what's the difference between beat and beat out?(if there's any)
For example what would be the correct form of using beat in this sentence : 1.She beat her enemy
2.She beat out her enemy

Comment: Please add in what context are these words to be used, because beat can refer to many things, including music, fighting with someone, a cop, and many more.

Comment: For example what would be the correct form of using beat in this sentence : 1.She beat her enemy     2.She beat out her enemy

Comment: Please add this to your question